# how to make script# preserve case of json records

Tags: .net, script#

I have

```
[Imported]
public sealed class ServerResult : Record
{

    public string Message;
    public int Result;
}
```

And my json server method does

```
return Json(new { Result = result, Message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but the js generated for

```
   jQuery.PostRequest<ServerResult>("status", null,
               delegate(ServerResult data)
               {
                    if(data.Result == 3)...
               }, "json");
```

says

```
          if(data.result === 3) ....
```

the case has been forced to all lowercase; which doesnt match what came over the wire

I can work round this by using lower case names in the c# but this breaks all my naming conventions.

PS - Nikhil - pls open source scipt#

version 0.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable automatic changes to casing you can use `[PreserveCase]`.

Like so:

```
[Imported]
public sealed class ServerResult : Record
{
    [PreserveCase]
    public string Message;
    [PreserveCase]
    public int Result;
}
```

You can also use `[ScriptName("MyExactNameInJavaScript")]` to be explicit about differences beyond just casing.

Comment: it seems that that does not work. I had to put preservecase on the method

Comment: @pm100 Are you sure? Maybe the script output was cached? I have used [PreserveCase] on fields like this in the past. Also, could you update your original question to mention which version of Script# you are using?